# LogLevel enabled, still can't see POST data on Apache server

Tags: apache

I really love the format of `forensic_module`, but I understand I may not be able to get this same level of nice formatting with `mod_dumpio.` However, the problem that I'm having is I have all the options enabled to log as much data as possible, but I still cannot see POST data anywhere in any log.

Here's what my virtualhost looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ServerName www.random.com
    ServerAlias random.com

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All 
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <IfModule log_forensic_module> 
        ForensicLog /var/www/html/forensic.log
    </IfModule> 

    <IfModule dumpio_module>
        DumpIOInput On
        DumpIOOutput On
        LogLevel trace7
    </IfModule>

    ErrorLog /var/www/html/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

While I can see my site (I have a local hosts entry for www.random.com), I can even post to the forum. In the log files, I can see the referrer header and other HTTP headers, but I do not see anything whatsoever from my POST parameters.

I've confirmed with web proxy that POST data is indeed being submitted, but I still don't know why it's not showing in any of the log files.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried `LogLevel debug` as well, and nothing resulted from that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like other posts suggest that this doesn't work either, so I'm just going with an alternative that indeed works:

```
<IfModule security2_module> 
    # Enable the module.
    SecRuleEngine On
    SecAuditEngine on

    # Setup logging in a dedicated file.
    SecAuditLog /path/to/directory/website-audit.log
    # Allow it to access requests body.
    SecRequestBodyAccess on
    SecAuditLogParts ABIFHZ

    # Setup default action.
    SecDefaultAction "nolog,noauditlog,allow,phase:2"

    # Define the rule that will log the content of POST requests.
    SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "^POST$" "chain,allow,phase:2,id:123"
    SecRule REQUEST_URI ".*" "auditlog"
</IfModule>
```